What are the exact lines that David Prowse spoke during the filming of the "I am your father" scene?
When the "I am your father" scene in Star Wars: the Empire strikes back was first being filmed, only Mark Hamill, George Lucas, and a few others knew the plot twist.  To prevent the secret from leaking, David Prowse (the actor in the Darth Vader suit) was given fake lines that were different from the dialogue in the finished movie.  What were the fake lines, specifically?  Were they recorded and is this information available anywhere?
According to the Wikipedia page on Darth Vader, which cites this page, the "I am your father" line itself was replaced by "Obi-Wan Kenobi is your father", while here it is claimed that the line was "Obi-Wan killed your father".
Also, what were the Darth Vader lines that came afterwards? (for instance, the "together father and son" lines must have been replaced too)

https://www.facebook.com/yahooentertainment/videos/lyin-luke-skywalker-mark-hamill-relishes-spreading-fake-sta/10156071531764832/ - Hamill says it's the latter. But then he's full of all kinds of nonsense these days, so who's to say?

"My real name is Dumbledore, and you shall not pass"

Is there a publicly available copy of the original script used by the actors?
